# VBA- Macro for copy and paste of dynamic info into summary tab

Tags: vba, excel

First question here and an issue that is melting my poor brain.

I have a Workbook and it has 6 tabs. These tabs are different divisions of a company. Each tab contains different headings like 'Employee Number' or 'First name' or 'Second name'. The heading aren't all in the same columns across the different tabs. (info being pulled from 6 different payrolls). The information is also changing on a monthly basis due to terminations and hires etc. The info is dynamic.

I want to consolidate these into one long list.

For example:

I want VBA to copy the info from column A in tab1 into Column A in tab7 (summary tab) and then copy the info from Column A in tab2 into the NEXT BLANK CELL in column A in tab7 and so on and so forth for the rest of the divisional tabs.

Finally Id like to be left with one unbroken list of all the info I need. I hope to be able to run a macro each month for this to save all the time wasting copying and pasting.

Would really appreciate some help. So far my efforts have ended in frustration.

```
Sub Test2()
'
' Test2 Macro
'Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim s2 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim iLastCellS2 As Excel.Range
Dim iLastRowS1 As Long

Set s1 = Sheets("BaulderStone")
Set s2 = Sheets("Flattened Contribution File ")

'iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

's1.Range("A1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "A")).Copy iLastCellS2

'Dim s3 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim s2 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim iLastCellS2 As Excel.Range
Dim iLastRowS1 As Long
Set s3 = Sheets("Retirement Living")
Set s2 = Sheets("Flattened Contribution File ")

' iLastRowS3 = s3.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

' Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

's3.Range("A1", s3.Cells(iLastRowS3, "A")).Copy iLastCellS2
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you try to be a little more focussed/specific. What have you tried thus far? Could you give us a sample of the code you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Got it. 

Sorry Stewart. New enough to this. Learning on the fly.

Comment: Since the data is dynamic, this is how you should do it. You need to use `.Find` to find the exact column which has the header. Once you know the column, get it's last row and the copy the range across in the summary sheet. More on `.Find` [HERE](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Hey Siddharth, 

There a number of columns with the same name. It is one Workbook with 6 separate "Divisional' sheets.

I'm not sure .FIND will work in this situation.

Comment: Siddharth has a point, you mentioned that each tab (called a sheet here for code purposes) has different headers in different columns.  How do you know that consolidation onto one sheet won't bungle the columns (as they have different headers).  Which headers are consistent?  After you answer that I have the solution for finding the last row handy: `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, #).End(xlUp).Row` where `#` is your column that you are at in your loop.

Comment: I guess its a case of assigning the exact column I want the code to copy from in the sheets, but I want it to paste to Column A in the summary sheet.

Comment: Are the different columns on the various sheets in relatively fixed positions?  That is, does each division have a fixed set of columns and are they always (for that division) output in the same order (or at least have the same header)?  Are you copying multiple columns from each sheet, or just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only copying a single column from each sheet, and that column is in a fixed position on each different source sheet:

```
Sub Test3()

    Const CONSOLIDATED As String = "Flattened Contribution File"
    Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet, shtC As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set shtC = wb.Worksheets(CONSOLIDATED)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If shtC Is Nothing Then
        Set shtC = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        shtC.Name = CONSOLIDATED
    End If

    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets

        Select Case sht.Name
            Case "BaulderStone": c = 1       'get from ColA
            Case "Retirement Living": c = 4  'get from ColD
            'add your other sheets here....
            Case Else: c = 0
        End Select

        If c > 0 Then
            sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, c), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp)).Copy _
              shtC.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If

    Next sht

End Sub
```

EDIT: if source and destination columns are the same for each source sheet then something like this should work.  Note: each source sheet must have headers in Row1

```
Sub Test4()

    Const CONSOLIDATED As String = "Flattened Contribution File"
    Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet, shtC As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long, numRows As Long
    Dim map, colSrc As String, colDest As String
    Dim destRow As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set shtC = wb.Worksheets(CONSOLIDATED)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If shtC Is Nothing Then
        Set shtC = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        shtC.Name = CONSOLIDATED
    End If

    destRow = 2

    'create 2-d array of source & dest columns A-->A, C-->B, D-->C
    map = [{"A","A";"C","B";"D","C"}]

    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
        'edit: add the sheet names you want to exclude from copying here
        '...or switch it around to check for names you *want* to consolidate...
        If sht.Name <> CONSOLIDATED And sht.Name <> "Report" _
           And sht.Name <> "whatever" Then

            '# of data rows....
            numRows = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

            For c = LBound(map, 1) To UBound(map, 1)

                colSrc = map(c, 1)
                colDest = map(c, 2)

                With sht
                    .Range(.Range(colSrc & "2"), .Range(colSrc & (numRows + 1))).Copy _
                          shtC.Range(colDest & destRow)
                End With
            Next c

            destRow = destRow + numRows

        End If
   Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim that it awesome. Looks good. I'm just going to run it and see how it goes. Many thanks.

Comment: Hey Tim, 


That worked awesome for the first column on the summary spreadsheet. If I wanted to take columns 2,3,4 and 5 from the source sheets and paste it into columns 2,3,4 and 5 in the summary sheet how would it change? I tried duplicating the code above and changing the case to the relevant column number but it is giving me


'Compile Error- Duplicaton error in Current Scope' and highligting 

    'CONSOLIDATED As String' in the code. 

Help is much appreciated and thanks a bunch for the help so far.

Comment: I should clarify. I found a way to have the data I need in the same columns across all source sheets. I need to copy and past these into one 'master' column now in the summary sheet. So far, your code has worked awesomely for getting the first column of each source sheet into the master sheet, and many many thanks, even for that. I am trying to get it to copy column B from each sheet and paste into Column B in the master sheet. Same for Column C, and D etc.

Comment: Hey Time,Its now taking the info a sheet that is irrelevant and pasting it into the summary sheet. Ill rephrase the above but I am very greatful, getting me out of a bind here.

Comment: My spreadsheet is set up as so. These are the names of the tabs.


Cont.Worksheet. , Verification , Report , DEMO , Masterfile , then sheet2 to sheet 14 inclusive.

I want the info in columns A,B,C,D,E etc in sheets 8 through 13 to go into their respective columns in sheet 14. Essentially combining all the 'lists' from sheets8 - 13 into one long list on sheet 14. Same for column B, C, D, E etc.

Comment: You're previous code was perfect for transferring the date in column A in each of sheets 8-13 into column A in sheet 14. The final part is doing the same thing for B,C,D,E etc.

Comment: See my edit on the line which checks the sheet name: you need to add whatever sheets are *not* to be copied from...